# Total power consumption in LTSpice

Tags: power, ltspice, dissipation

I know how to measure the average power dissipated on a component but I have a very big circuit with lots of components so I am looking for a short way to calculate the total avg power in the whole circuit using Ltspice

Answer (score 2):

Use a zero ohm resistor in the power feed and plot the current through that resistor multiplied by the power feed voltage. I don't know if this can be averaged but in micro-cap if the zero ohm resistor were called R97 and the supply voltage was labelled as V57 then the average power would be: -

avg(I(R97)*V57)

Comment: assuming a voltage source as the single power feed, you can just take the voltage and current from that source directly

Comment: @PlasmaHH yes you can and I was going to follow up with adding a capacitor to do some "RC" filtering but I got way-laid!

Comment: We're really not interested in what you do in your personal time, no matter how good it was for you...

Comment: Marginally amusing.